# Store data frames after splitting

Tags: r

```
Data:-

Name   Age   Sex
 A      5     F
 B      4     F
 A      10    M
```

Consider a sample data frame like the one above. I use the Split function to group all the data having  the same name.

```
split(test, interaction(test$Name), drop = TRUE)
```

**test** is the data frame here and I get the desired output.

```
Output:-

$A
    Name Age Sex
1    A   5   F
3    A  10   M

$B
    Name Age Sex
2    B   4   F
```

The issue I am having is that I need to store this data as separate dataframes to work on them later. Please advice.

Edit:- I can use **'$'** after the split function and create a function which puts the unique Names after the '$' and store the output as a data frame. I am trying it and will post it if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the following you get two new variables `a` and `b` with the elements of the splitting result:

```
Map(function(x,y) assign(x,y, envir = .GlobalEnv), x = letters[1:2], y = split(df, interaction(df$Name), drop = TRUE))
$a
  Name Age Sex
1    A   5   F
3    A  10   M

$b
  Name Age Sex
2    B   4   F
```

Comment: How can I name the data frame in this case with the unique value that I have used the Split function with. I mean if the name was "jack" and I want to name the data frame as jack then how can I do it. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: You can replace the `x` argument, which is `letters[1:2]` in this case, with whichever names you want.